# how to redirect http to https with glassfish v4

Tags: http, redirect, https, glassfish

We have created a web site on Glassfish v4 and it using port 8080 for http and port 8081 for https. Our cisco firewall forwards requests to port 80 to port 8080 and requests to port 443 to port 8081.

But we don't want users to be able to access http site at all. We want to redirect all requests to http site to https. How can it be done?
In the Glassfish Admin panel, we have made changes to Configurations -> server-config -> Network Listeners -> http-listener-1 and http-listener-2 to redirect to port 8081 under HTTP tab but it is not working.
Users are still able to see the http site from outside.
Thank you for you help.

[image]

Comment: If you are also using Java 7, this answer helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25432386/1435605

Answer (score 9):

Open web.xml inside WEB-INF of war file. Add following lines of code inside `<web-app>` tag.

```xml
<web-app>
  ...
    <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Viewpoint Secure URLs</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
      </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

See also [The Java EE 6 Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncbk/index.html) for more information.