# How to display maintenance page my web app is undeployed, Using redirect request to another port

Tags: java, glassfish

In a web app using java, I want to display one page that say application is under construction, though the app is undeployed, want to redirect request from 8080 to 80

Answer (score 0):

Try using Port Unification feature of glassfish while undeploying application to redirect traffic to an intended port from undeployed port as explained by jdigi82 at [Glassfish v4 - java 7 - Port Unification - Error - not able to redirect http to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25122025/glassfish-v4-java-7-port-unification-error-not-able-to-redirect-http-to?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and restore after deploying application