# StartSSL Domain Validation Cert with Glassfish 4

Tags: ssl, glassfish

I just can´t get the ssl certificate from StartSSL to work.

I have a running glassfish version on my local system and made the changes there before I uploaded them onto my virtual server.

Here is what I did:

**1. Create a CSR**

"openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout yourname.key -out yourname.csr"

**2. Pasted CSR Context (between -BEGIN / END CERTIFICATE REQUEST--**

**3. Downloaded the generated Certificate Files from StartSSL**

Received the following files:

- root.crt
- 1_Intermediate.crt
- 2.www.domain.de.crt

**4. Changed Masertpassword for Glassfish**

**5. Created keystore:**

```
 keytool -keysize 2048 -genkey -alias Domain -keyalg RSA -dname “CN=www.domain.de,O=yourCompany,L=yourCity,S=yourS tate,C=yourCountry” -keypass yourmasteradminpw -storepass yourmasteradminpw -keystore keystore.jks
```

**6. Imported Files to keystore:**

```
# keytool -import -alias startsslcert -keystore keystore.jks -trustcacerts -file root.crt
# keytool -import -alias startsslsub -keystore keystore.jks -trustcacerts -file 1_Intermediate.crt
# keytool -import -alias domainname -keystore keystore.jks -trustcacerts -file 2_www.domain.crt
```

**7. Imported files to cacerts.jks:**

```
# keytool -import -alias startsslcert -keystore cacerts.jks -trustcacerts -file root.crt
# keytool -import -alias startsslsub -keystore cacerts.jks -trustcacerts -file 1_Intermediate.crt
```

After that, I have changed the s1as in domain.xml to the alias of point 5. Replaced the cacerts, keystore and admin-keyfile with the new ones on my v-server

I checked if the keystore.jks and the cacerts.jks file use the glassfish masterpassword as password.

Now the website AND the glassfish admin console are not accesible anymore. I

**Questions:**

1. At point 1 I entered some information like in this
   [tutorial](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/generate-a-csr-with-openssl/) at "Create a CSR". Do this information have to be exactly the when creating the keystore?
2. I read in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935725/glassfish-v4-ssl-admin-no-longer-works/34952975#34952975) that the admin-principal has to be updated after the s1as has been changed. The problem is, that I can´t run the **enable-secure-admin-principal** command because the domain is not starting - event though the command **asadmin start-domain** was successfully executed. After I started the domain I checked if the domain is running with **list-domains** but it said, that no domain is running... . The server.log file **doesn´t** show errors.

In my domain.xml file I have this part as admin-principal:

```
<secure-admin special-admin-indicator="4de31578-ac8c-49cf-884e-77faada83599" enabled="true">
<secure-admin-principal dn="CN=localhost,OU=GlassFish,O=Oracle Corporation,L=Santa Clara,ST=California,C=US"></secure-admin-principal>
<secure-admin-principal dn="CN=localhost-instance,OU=GlassFish,O=Oracle Corporation,L=Santa Clara,ST=California,C=US"></secure-admin-principal>
</secure-admin>
```