# how to set ssl after changing vps for payara server?

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish, self-signed, payara

I used self signed ssl on vps for payara (fork of glassfish)
then i duplicated the payara on another server then https on 2nd vps doesnt work 
and i create new self signed ssl by [this tutorial](http://blog.payara.fish/securing-payara-server-with-custom-ssl-certificate).

now https works on my application but i cant enable-secure-admin or open payara control panel
it gives me sslhandshake exception.

Comment: 'Set SSL'? Do you mean how to set the SSL *certificate*?

Comment: Yes ca signed certificate

Comment: Did you change the admin alias? Check these answers (and comments) for useful information in managing the admin alias:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29280729/212224  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/34952975/212224

Comment: Enable secure domain gives sslhandshakeexception